# django extended built in user model not allowing to login in admin

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-admin

i am using django 1.8 for my app and i am using postgresql.I have successfully created a super user and can login to my admin panel after configuring all the postgresql settings in my settings.py file.but after that **i have just decided to extend my django built in user model** and thats why i have created a new app namely authentication and wrote this model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager


class AccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **kwargs):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a valid email address.')

        if not kwargs.get('username'):
            raise ValueError('Users must have a valid username.')

        account = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email), username=kwargs.get('username')
        )

        account.set_password(password)
        account.save()

        return account

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **kwargs):
        account = self.create_user(email, password, **kwargs)
        account.is_admin = True
        account.save()

        return account


class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
    tagline = models.CharField(max_length=140, blank=True)

    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = AccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        return ' '.join([self.first_name, self.last_name])

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.first_name
```

and then i have migrated it after adding a new line in my settings.py which is

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'authentication.Account'
```

but after that i can't able to login into my admin.

to solve this,i have created a superuser for my newly created account model.but problem hasn't been solved.

to test whats going wrong,i have commented out the **AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'authentication.Account'** like this

```
#AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'authentication.Account'
```

and then its allowing me to login to my admin with old username and password which actually i have set when i have configured postgresql and create superuser.

**EDIT**
after creating superuser for my Account model,i am trying to login to my admin, giving the newly created email address as username and new password,but now i am facing the following error

```
AttributeError at /admin/login/
'Account' object has no attribute 'is_staff'
```

Answer (score 0):

To have a user model suitable to use with django admin, you need to extend `AbstractUser` - An abstract base class implementing a fully featured User model with admin-compliant permissions.

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L293

Or add additional fields to your model. At least you need `is_active` and `is_staff`

Answer (score 0):

i have solved the problem,i have added the following medthods in **Account** model

```
@property
def is_staff(self):
    return self.is_admin

def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
    return self.is_admin

def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
    return self.is_admin
```

and now i can successfully login in my admin without having the error like

```
'Account obejects has no attribute like stuff'
```

or

```
'Account obejects has no attribute like has_module_perms'
```